# Check for thread shutdown and execute a task once it shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating a fixed-size thread pool with 10 threads as follows:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; ++i) {
   executorService.execute(factory.get());
}
```

Now, after spawning 10 threads, a runnable is being executed by each of them. Runnable here is provided by factory.get()

Now, I wanted to do a thing that as soon as a thread gets shutdown, i.e. it has completed a task, it picks another runnable again and start running it. So, basically check for all 10 threads state and execute a runnable again if the thread is shutdown.

I know I can do something like, in which I can call the executorService shutdown() method as follows to do that:

```
   while (!executorService.isShutdown()) {
        try {
            executorService.execute(factory.get());
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
            if (!executorService.isShutdown())
                log.warn("task submission rejected");
        }
    }
```

But in this approach, issue is that I am keep on calling the execute function which would increase LinkedBlockingQueue and won't serve my purpose.

If I can somehow check the Threads state, that would be good because then, it would avoid the overhead of going back to get more work from the executor service.

Please suggest how can I do that in code.

Comment: Couple of suggestions: 1) you could flip this around and make it less about the state of the thread and more about the state of the Runnable: is there something in your Runnable-derived type that you can subscribe to or ask to notify you when it's job is done? 2) Consider using a Callable instead of a Runnable; that way you can ask the returned Future `isDone()` to ascertain whether the task is complete or not.

Comment: `would increase LinkedBlockingQueue and won't serve my purpose` What is it you're trying to achieve? If you are blocking before submitting tasks to the executor, you're not really utilizing the threadpool properly. What's the issue with the queue buffering the tasks?

Comment: finishing a task shouldn't shutdown a thread, that defeats the purpose of having a thread pool. not clear what you're trying to accomplish but I suspect you should just let the executor do its thing and not micromanage it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bounded executor. The following is [code](http://jcip.net/listings/BoundedExecutor.java) by Brian Goetz from [jcip](http://jcip.net/)

```
/**
 * BoundedExecutor
 * <p/>
 * Using a Semaphore to throttle task submission
 *
 * @author Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
 */
public class BoundedExecutor {
    private final Executor exec;
    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    public BoundedExecutor(Executor exec, int bound) {
        this.exec = exec;
        this.semaphore = new Semaphore(bound);
    }

    public void submitTask(final Runnable command)
            throws InterruptedException {
        semaphore.acquire();
        try {
            exec.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        command.run();
                    } finally {
                        semaphore.release();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Then just create and use it:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
BoundedExecutor boundedExecutor = new BoundedExecutor(executorService,10);

while (!executorService.isShutdown()) {
    try {
        boundedExecutor.submitTask(factory.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

This way you will always have 10 threads running, new tasks will only be submitted after the old ones will complete and you can stop the execution by shutting down the executor.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a thread pool if you're going to run 10 threads continually? Just start 10 threads yourself.

Why have a "controller" thread on top of the 10 worker threads? Just let each thread ask for the next task to execute.

The following assumes that `factory.get()` is thread-safe.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        for (;;) {
            Runnable r = factory.get(); // <-- must be thread-safe
            if (r == null)
                break; // stop thread if no more tasks to execute
            try {
                r.run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // log exception here
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

If needed, save the 10 thread objects in an array.

If you want to be able to shutdown the threads without having `factory.get()` returning null, add a volatile boolean, and check it in the loop.

Comment: In this case, how will we handle the case where the thread got killed in between?

Comment: I mean how are you handling the case of Interruption? What if one of the thread got interrupted. In that case, we want to kill all threads, right?

Comment: @hatellla A thread is only interrupted if you decide to interrupt it. If you want interrupt to shut it down, then you add logic to make that happen. It's your code, you decide what it should do. I just gave an example to get you on the right track.